# Since when android restart an app after a crash?

Tags: android

I remember to have seen that Android started to restart apps when these crash for the first time. But I can't find this statement in the documentation or release notes.

Do you know since which OS/SDK version this happen? Maybe I was dreaming?

Answer (score 2):

I've tested with 4 different model devices and the behaviour seems to vary on device rather than android version.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate very much your effort :)

Answer (score 2):

Auto starting after a crash is not a standard behavior of Android. More commonly after an app crash, you are shown a dialog with an option to open the app again if you choose to do so. You can see the dialog in the following document.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/games/optimize/crash

Also, I think auto-restart of an app after a crash is not a good feature. If there is something wrong with the app causing a crash when you launch the app, then there is a good chance it may crash again with the auto relaunch. Why have the user see the crash again unnecessarily.

Comment: That's it! Actually is a dialog, but I remember that was introduced in some specific version. I guess as says @Nezih this depends more in the manufacturer than the android version it self.

Comment: I awarded the bounty to @Nezih because android actually restart the app in the first in some devices/versions of android. On a pixel you get the dialog only the second time the app crashes in the same session.

Comment: Given neither of both answered the question, so the bounty I gave it for the effort of testing. Anyway, I thank you for the research.